# Can I write to a file instead of the console when debugging?

Tags: debugging, xamarin

In Xamarin, I'm often using the Console (WriteLine) to debug an application.

Is this possible to write some lines directly to a file somewhere on the host machine instead of using the Console to debug? I don't want to write a file on the phone as I'll use this file in realtime on the development machine.

Comment: If you work in console, perhaps you can do it by appending " > filename.txt" after your console command.

Comment: I think it will be interpreted just like any other character if I just append it to System.Console.WriteLine. Otherwise the console would get crazy. :)

Comment: Aha, why not open a file and write to it instead of Console. Sorry, just brainstorming, I used Java long time ago.

Comment: It runs on the device, I need to access it in realtime on the host.

Comment: It would be helpful if you specified iOS or Xamarin.  However, in either case the answer is probably "No".  In iOS, Console is aliased to the device log, which can be accessed from a host.  Beyond that you would probably need a webservice to write your log info to.

Comment: Oh... Socket! I didn't think about it. A that's PCL-izable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way:

- Use Console.WriteLine in your app.
- On your host, execute this:

  ```
  /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch --logdev > ~/myfile.log
  ```

And now your Console.WriteLine output will end up in `~/myfile.log`. The downside is that you'll get *everything* written to the Device Log, both from iOS itself and any other apps (this can be significant sometimes). However it should be possible to filter out only your output by some clever grep usage.

The more involved approach would be to redirect Console.WriteLine output to some sort of network stream that sends the data over wifi to the host machine (or a web service for instance).

The easy part is to redirect Console.WriteLine output:

```
Console.SetOut (myNetworkStream);
```

The rest will be left as an exercise for the reader, since that wasn't part of the question :)